# How to convert mat file including 4916 pictures (375x375x3) into a numpy array?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I want to extract pictures in [5000BOLD](https://github.com/nchang430/BOLD5000-Scripts/blob/master/all_img_names.mat) which is a Matlab file including 4916 color pictures. When I import them in Python using the following:

```
import scipy.io as sio
mat = sio.loadmat('all_imgs.mat')
```

I get a dictionary `type(mat): dict`. How can I change this file into a numpy array which ables me to access to each picture and plot it? Since each picture is `375x375x3`, I should have an array `375x375x3x4916`.

Also, using `mat.keys()` I have the following, which I have no idea what each element means:

```
dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'all_imgs'])
```

> Is there any direct way to use this dictionary file `mat` directly and plot a specific picture using imshow?

Comment: The `loadmat` documentation should make it clear that it returns a dictionary, and that you access individual variables by key,  e.g. `mat['all_imgs']`.

Comment: When I use `mat['all_imgs']` I get a numpy array `1x4916`. First, why `mat['all_imgs']` gives me a numpy array? Second, what is the magic of `['all_imgs']`.

Comment: Do you have any other experience with python? or numpy?

Comment: That file is too big for me to download and open myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a smaller file:

```
In [33]: from scipy import io                                                                                   
In [34]: io.loadmat('../Downloads/all_img_names.mat')
```

loading without assignment gives me a print display of the file contents (I don't recommend this with the big image file):

```
Out[34]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: GLNXA64, Created on: Thu Oct 19 14:20:48 2017',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'all_img_names': array([[array(['airplanecabin1.jpg'], dtype='<U18'),
         array(['scenes'], dtype='<U6')],
        [array(['airplanecabin3.jpg'], dtype='<U18'),
         array(['scenes'], dtype='<U6')],
        [array(['airplanecabin5.jpg'], dtype='<U18'),
         array(['scenes'], dtype='<U6')],
        ...,
        [array(['yogastudio2.jpg'], dtype='<U15'),
         array(['scenes'], dtype='<U6')],
        [array(['yogastudio3.jpg'], dtype='<U15'),
         array(['scenes'], dtype='<U6')],
        [array(['yogastudio4.jpg'], dtype='<U15'),
         array(['scenes'], dtype='<U6')]], dtype=object)}
```

Looking specifically at the `all_img_names` key.  That corresponds to a variable of that name in the source MATLAB workspace.  Note that is object dtype.  Like cell it can contain other arrays:

```
In [36]: io.loadmat('../Downloads/all_img_names.mat')['all_img_names'].shape                                    
Out[36]: (4916, 2)
```

And looking at the first 'row' of that array, it too is `object` dtype, with 2 string arrays - the name of the file, and some sort of category label:

```
In [37]: io.loadmat('../Downloads/all_img_names.mat')['all_img_names'][0]                                       
Out[37]: 
array([array(['airplanecabin1.jpg'], dtype='<U18'),
       array(['scenes'], dtype='<U6')], dtype=object)
```

Hopefully that gives you an idea of how to explore the contents of `mat['all_imgs']`.

```
mat['all_imgs'][0,0]
```

may be a 2d array.  But if it is some sort of image encoding, you may have to open it with `cv2`.  But without downloading that big file, I can't help further.

Comment: That was really helpful. I could extract the required file that I needed. Just let me know how I can get rid of `[]` when I build dataframe out of this slice `mat['all_imgs'][3:5,:]` using `pd.DataFrame(mat['all_imgs'][3:5,:], index = ['a','b'], columns = [1,2])`?